# Would be correct to put だ in this phrase?

Tags: grammar

I was reading some online articles about Japenese Grammar and one of it's examples were:

> 静かな人 meaning *the quiet person*

Although while I was reflectling about this phrase I was wondering if I could use だ in this exact same phrase. For example, let's suppose I'm talking about Erickさん, can I say:

> Erickさんは静かな人だ and in it's polite form Erickさんは静かな人です

Comment: Yes. It's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything you just posted works without problems.  Hopefully this will clear things up.

When you say `静かだ` you are literally saying `is quiet` in English.  The same can be said of い adjectives.  Ending a sentence with `大きい` really just says `is big.`  With adjectives, the to be verb is already built in.  With い adjectives saying です after the adjective, while grammatically correct is not always necessary.  You would add です to be polite to the listener.

When you attach the adjective to a noun, `静かな人` you no longer have the to be verb as a closer.  In fact, in these situations, you can safely assume that there is no verb, and that the adjective + noun form a noun clause.  In short, you need a verb, and だ/です will work for you.  The same will apply to い adjectives as well.